# Kibana 4, Logstash dashboard: how do I require Nginx authentication when saving but allow anonymous views?

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

**I would like to require auth_basic nginx authentication to save all kibana 4 dashboards but allow anyone to view dashboards without authentication.**

I recently installed an ELK (Elasticsearch 1.4.5, Logstash 1:1.5.2-1, and Kibana 4.1.1) stack on Ubuntu 14.04 using a DigitalOcean [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Because kibana uses browser based javascript to sends queries to elasticsearch, I'm not sure how to figure out what to secure.

DigitalOcean provides an nginx config to fully secure access to kibana 4.

```
FILE:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
    listen      80;
    return 301 https://logstash.nyc.3top.com;
}
server {
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    server_name logstash.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/kibana.access.log;

    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Elastic provided an nginx [sample config](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/3.0/sample/nginx.conf) to accomplish this for Kibana 3 but not Kibana 4:

```
server {
  listen                *:80 ;

  server_name           kibana.myhost.org;
  access_log            /var/log/nginx/kibana.myhost.org.access.log;

  location / {
    root  /usr/share/kibana3;
    index  index.html  index.htm;
  }

  location ~ ^/_aliases$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
  location ~ ^/.*/_aliases$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
  location ~ ^/_nodes$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
  location ~ ^/.*/_search$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }
  location ~ ^/.*/_mapping {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
  }

  # Password protected end points
  location ~ ^/kibana-int/dashboard/.*$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    limit_except GET {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
      auth_basic "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
    }
  }
  location ~ ^/kibana-int/temp.*$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    limit_except GET {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
      auth_basic "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd;
    }
  }
}
```

**Does anyone know how to do this for Kibana 4?**

Here is are my config files for elasticsearch and kibana:

/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

```
network.host: localhost
```

/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml

```
port: 5601
host: "localhost"
elasticsearch_url: "http://localhost:9200"
elasticsearch_preserve_host: true
kibana_index: ".kibana"
default_app_id: "discover"
request_timeout: 300000
shard_timeout: 0
verify_ssl: true
bundled_plugin_ids:
 - plugins/dashboard/index
 - plugins/discover/index
 - plugins/doc/index
 - plugins/kibana/index
 - plugins/markdown_vis/index
 - plugins/metric_vis/index
 - plugins/settings/index
 - plugins/table_vis/index
 - plugins/vis_types/index
 - plugins/visualize/index
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to leverage **nginx's conditional capabilitie**s to achieve this. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/r0mdau/db31403c0338b057bc7a#quick-start) might be a good starting point. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thanks, the link is helpful.  although it makes the entire site read only and seems to restrict the ability to apply new filters, it gave me a $request_uri to experiment with.  I'm going to see if I can find/guess $request_uri for dashboard saves, config saves, etc based on this.  I may not get to this until later in the week but I'll post an update when I have one.